# Does WindowInsets.isRound() work when creating a watchface?

Tags: android, wear-os

I've extended CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine following the examples on [android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/issues.html), but on the 3 devices I've tested (Moto360, the round emulator, and the square emulator), isRound() is always false. onApplyWindowInsets is called, but the passed in insets are wrong (well, except for the square emulator).

I saw that this was a known issue in December, but that the later emulators (and the Moto360) should be fixed. Is there some line I've forgotten to call?

```
public class WatchfaceService extends CanvasWatchFaceService {
    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new Engine();
    }

    private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
        @Override
        public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
            super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
            // insets.isRound() always returns false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was the moment when the different methods are executed. First onCreate, then onApplyWindowsInset and then onDraw. Thus, you need to apply the right background images under the onDraw method. Otherwise isRound() will not have the right value because it has not been set yet. Try to compare the value of isRound() within onCreate and then under onDraw. You will see the difference.